# Rate limit policy settings is not applied using AspNetCoreRateLimit

Tags: api, asp.net-core, rate-limiting

I am using AspNetCoreRateLimit version 4.0.1 and I have done all the setup in .net core 6 web api. I can see rate limit is working when I send a call via postman.

However, when I add IpRateLimitPolicies with specific IP address, the settings won't be applied.
I use postman and this time in the proxy I added the ip address to 127.0.0.1. I can see the ip hitting the api is set correctly when I use `Request.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress;`

I registered them as follow in program.cs:

```
    _serviceCollection.AddOptions();
    _serviceCollection.AddMemoryCache();
    _serviceCollection.Configure<IpRateLimitOptions>(builder.Configuration.GetSection("IpRateLimiting"));
     _serviceCollection.Configure<IpRateLimitPolicies>(builder.Configuration.GetSection("IpRateLimitPolicies"));
     _serviceCollection.AddInMemoryRateLimiting();
     _serviceCollection.AddSingleton<IIpPolicyStore, MemoryCacheIpPolicyStore>();
     _serviceCollection.AddSingleton<IRateLimitCounterStore, MemoryCacheRateLimitCounterStore>();
     _serviceCollection.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
     _serviceCollection.AddSingleton<IRateLimitConfiguration, RateLimitConfiguration>();
```

Also added:
`app.UseIpRateLimiting();`

My appsettings also looks like:

```
 {
  "IpRateLimiting": {
    "EnableEndpointRateLimiting": false,
    "StackBlockedRequests": false,
    "RealIPHeader": "X-Real-IP",
    "ClientIdHeader": "X-ClientId",
    "IpWhitelist": [ ],
    "EndpointWhitelist": [],
    "ClientWhitelist": [],
    "HttpStatusCode": 429,
    "GeneralRules": [
      {
        "Endpoint": "*",
        "Period": "10s",
        "Limit": 1
      }
    ]
  },
  "IpRateLimitPolicies": {
    "IpRules": [
      {
        "Ip": "127.0.0.1",
        "Rules": [
          {
            "Endpoint": "*",
            "Period": "20s",
            "Limit": 2
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

But apparently the settings under IpRateLimitPolicies won't be applied.

I wonder if I have missed anything here?

Thank you

Comment: Please show the all content in your appsettings.json file and hide your sensitive info.

Comment: since we are using lunchsettings.json for other stuff, the content of appsettings is exactly what I shared already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently I have missed some configuration in program.cs or startup.cs:
https://github.com/stefanprodan/AspNetCoreRateLimit/issues/305

Since we are using startup I have added the following in Configure method

> 

var ipPolicyStore = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService();
ipPolicyStore.SeedAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

Answer (score 1):

After testing, I think the AspNetCoreRateLimit package is not compatible in .net5 and .net6. Maybe the .net core3.1 version will be more stable.

You can submit issues on github.

Comment: Thank you - I have raised an issue there and as soon as I get an answer I will add a comment here: https://github.com/stefanprodan/AspNetCoreRateLimit/issues/305